# The given expression is always of the provided type

Tags: c#, compiler-warnings, reference-type

Why does Visual Studio warn about this when using `is` on value types, but doesn't when on reference types? Lines 1 and 2 raise the warning, while lines 3 and 4 don't.

```
if (5 is object)
if (new Point() is object)

if ("12345" is object)
if (new StringBuilder() is object)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because it was not implemented by Microsoft. But it is e.g. implemented by [JetBrains ReSharper](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/).

Visual Studio shows 2 compiler warnings:

[image: Visual Studio]

ReSharper shows 4 warnings:

[image: ReSharper]

Comment: While this is great within Visual Studio, it doesn't breaks the build when `treat warnings as errors` is used. See this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3361495/2557263

Answer (score 9):

It's a heuristic and heuristics are, by definition, incomplete.

The source code for this heuristic can be found here: [Roslyn Source: Binder.GetIsOperatorConstantResult](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/b4c771f02b93ede0f0b2dde0df2c5278e47d274c/src/Compilers/CSharp/Portable/Binder/Binder_Operators.cs#L2744). The code contains the following quote:

```
// The result of "x is T" can be statically determined to be true if x is an expression 
// of non-nullable value type T. If x is of reference or nullable value type then
// we cannot know, because again, the expression value could be null or it could be good.
```

Obviously, the heuristic could be improved if it is *known* (as in your examples) that `x` is a non-null expression. However, as [Eric Lippert writes in his blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2012/09/12/static-analysis-of-is/), every warning (in fact - every compiler feature) has a cost, and, apparently, the Roslyn developers did not consider this feature important enough for this release.

As [Thomas Weller's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41808298) shows, there are third-party solutions filling this gap.

Comment: Great answer :)

Answer (score -1):

The `is` operator cannot be overloaded.

> Note that the `is` operator only considers reference conversions, boxing conversions, and unboxing conversions. Other conversions, such as **user-defined conversions**, are not considered.

Source: [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/scekt9xw.aspx)

Comment: Please use the citation character > for cited content